# condition based controller routing angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to pass a hidden value or some optional parameter which not part of URL to change between the states based on the param. So i tried like

```
<a ui-sref="state2({key:'value', optional: 'B'})">Send param and go to page 2</a>
```

In the route provider

```
$stateProvider
  .state('state2', {
  url: "/:key",
  templateUrl: "state1.html",
  params: {
    optional: null
  },
  controller: 'contollerA'
})
  .state('state3', {
  url: "/:key",
  templateUrl: "state3.html",
  controller: 'contollerB'
})
  .state('state4', {
  url: "/:key",
  templateUrl: "state4.html",
  controller: 'contollerC'
})
```

In the controller

```
.controller('contollerA', function($scope, $stateParams, $state) {
    if ($stateParams.optional === 'B') {
        $state.go('state3');
    } else {
        $state.go('state4');
    }
})
```

but this is not working as the error showing on browser console some thing like

invalid state reference

What is the way to achieve this?

Comment: A dirty way would be to pass it through `$rootscope`

Comment: Which version of ui-router you are using?

Comment: I am using angular ui-router 0.2.15 and angular 1.4.8

Answer (score 0):

Because state2 doesn't contain the param "key" in config. Replace

```
.state('state2', {
  url: "/:key",
  templateUrl: "state1.html",
  params: {
     optional: null
  },
 controller: 'contollerA'
})
```

with

```
.state('state2', {
  url: "/:key?optional",
  templateUrl: "state1.html",
  params: {
     optional: null,
     key: null
  },
 controller: 'contollerA'
})
```

Comment: still same issue after this change